# Removing Google maps base layer from Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I need to remove the base layer of google maps dynamically. User can add or remove the base layer.Because I am using more layer on top of it.Is there any function in google maps api to remove the basemap and leave it as a blank.

Comment: I think you are more likely to attract potential answerers by including a snippet of you code so far that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The idea behind a base-map actually is that it allways IS on base of your whole map, so no you cannot remove it. If you don´t like Google-Maps why using it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your map's style to a custom style, in which you will set the visibility value as off for all layers.

Use this [simple wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to create your own style.